# How to check service status where service is stoped

Tags: node.js

I noted very weird behavior when I want to run service apache2 status on my node. This is code:

```
 app.post('/getStatus', jsonParser, function(req,res){

   exec("service apache2 status", function(err, stdout){
    if(err) throw err;
    var statuspmtatmp = /Active: [a-z]* [\(][a-z]*[\)]/g.exec(stdout.toString())[0];

    res.json(statuspmtatmp);
   });

});
```

When I run this command when apache is running everything is ok, but when I stop apache and they I try to check status I get error:

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c service apache2 status
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

What is wrong? Why when apache is running everything is ok?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for errors and throwing the error on this line:

```
if(err) throw err;
```

So the execution stop and throw an error

Do

```
if(err){
   //code to handle the error
}
```

As you can read in [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

> If a callback function is provided, it is called with the arguments (error, stdout, stderr). On success, error will be null. **On error, error will be an instance of Error.** The error.code property will be the exit code of the child process while error.signal will be set to the signal that terminated the process. **Any exit code other than 0 is considered to be an error.**

Comment: why on this line? why is not passing the code I see that in stout I have information that service is stooped?

Comment: Worked? I added some clarity to my answer maybe now is clearer

Comment: Ok, but I want to know what is the status if I will use err I wouldn't know if error appear because there was for example permission problem or another. I have status 3 and signal null. How I can take information that apache is not running now?????